# JAVASCRIPT - jQuery - Inserting value into input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I was wondering why this code won't work for me. I am trying to append value from database into input field of this submit button as I want to send it back to another table in my database. Thanks!

```
  </div>
        <form>
         <input type="input"  value="'+ jobpost.jobID+'" id="jobID"/> 
         <br>
          <button type="submit" id="submit3" name="submit3" 
         onclick="myFunctionjobStatus();">Submit</button></form></div>
```

I am using the following ajax post to send data to my php file to enter into the database. Please see below.

```
 function myFunctionjobStatus() {
     var jobID = document.getElementById("jobID").value;

  //AJAX code to submit form.
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8888/EduSubOct/jobstatus.php",
        data: { userEmail: localStorage.getItem("email"), jobID: 
        jobID}, 
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            alert("Request Sent");

        }
      });

  }
```

php file -

```
  <?php



 // Selecting Database 

   include_once 'dbh.php';

  /Here we fetch the data from the URL that was passed from our HTML 
  form
$userEmail = $_POST['userEmail'];
$jobID = $_POST['jobID'];


   $sql =  "INSERT INTO jobStatus (email, jobID) VALUES 
('$userEmail','$jobID');";

   mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 ?>
```

Comment: Can you share a little more details about your approach?

Comment: I think this is not the way to concatenate objects in PHP `value="'+ jobpost.jobID+'"`.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: `value="<?php echo $jobpost.jobID;?>"`  I think.

Comment: Since you wish to use an Ajax request, you should have a button with `type="button"`... With a `type="submit`, the form submits to self (since there is no action attribute defined) and the page reloads.